# Custom input mask in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mask

I want to generate an input type of text with custom mask like `--day/--night` and user replace `-` just with numbers. any suggestion? Please help me out here.

```
duration: --day/--night
```

Comment: Don't try doing that in a single input.  Use two inputs with adjacent spans or labels containing the "day" and "night" text.

Comment: tanx, but is there any way if I have to do this?

Comment: Yes! There is a way to do this. You will have to use `keyup` event and reformat string each time you detect a key stroke. Then replace non digit characters with blank using regular expressions.

Comment: Can't be that hard -> **http://jsfiddle.net/z3083kvb/**

Comment: Yes you can, bot don't - (i) it's hard to code, (ii) it doesn't make for a friendly UI, (iii) to access the data, you have to parse out the input string - disadvantages all round.

Answer (score 0):

Using two inputs is much more efficient.

But if you really want to do this, yes you can do it. You would need to check the input value every time user inputs a character and format the value to what you would like. You can also manipulate the cursor position using `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties.

There are also a number of mask plugins for inputs.
http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/mask/

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

Make a placeholder "--" where the user can write the things in. Here is a short example what I mean:

```
duration: <input placeholder="--" maxlength="2">day/<input placeholder="--" maxlength="2">night
```

Answer (score 0):

Telerik offer a free version of their "Kendo UI" JavaScript code. Here's an example of what you want: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/maskedtextbox/index

Here's the free code: http://www.telerik.com/download/kendo-ui-core

Here's their masked input code hosted on Github: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/kendo.maskedtextbox.js

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to write this type of code but you can use this code for this type of formatting.

```
<div>
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <!-- or set via JS -->
    <input id="phone" type="text" />
  </div>
```

jquery code

```
   $(":input").inputmask();

    $("#phone").inputmask({"mask": "99/99"});
```

see the codepen link **[click here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ErjVdX)**